# Unauthorized client refused - frappe/erpnext development setup with docker (code oss - manjaro)

Tags: vscode-devcontainer, erpnext, frappe

I am trying to configure frappe/erpnext on my laptop where I have Manjaro Linux installed, I am following step by step what is indicated here:
https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker/blob/main/docs/development.md
but I get  Connection error: Unauthorized client refused.

I have been looking for the causes and it seems to be because I am using Code-Oss instead of VSCode directly, but I am not sure, and I would like to know if anyone has had the same problem if they have been able to solve it without uninstalling code-oss that can help me.

System details:

```
CODE OSS Version: 1.77.1
Commit: b7886d7461186a5eac768481578c1d7ca80e2d21
Date: 2023-04-05T17:02:20.045Z
Electron: 19.1.9
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.1.25-1-MANJARO
Sandboxed: No
```

looks the logs:

TERMINAL: https://pastebin.com/8q9QaLjW

OUTPUT: https://pastebin.com/JrQZMYTF